# Iterating to create new data frames based on column value of an exisiting data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently, I have a data frame that has census data for cities over time. The columns are:

> ["Name","Metric", "2000Q1", "2000Q2", ...,"2020Q1"]

I am hoping to create seperate data frames for each city. The cities are named in the "Name" column. So, there are 13 rows that include the city Omaha for example that I want to pull into a separate data frame. I want to be able to iterate over the data frame to create new data frames selecting only the city's metrics. Right now, I only have 6 city's data in so I can do it manually as seen below, but how would I do this without manually inputting the city names?

```
Charleston = df.loc[df.Name=="Charleston"]
Denver = df.loc[df.Name=="Denver"]
Houston = df.loc[df.Name=="Houston"]
Nashville = df.loc[df.Name=="Nashville"]
Omaha = df.loc[df.Name=="Omaha"]
Portland = df.loc[df.Name=="Portland"]
Washington = df.loc[df.Name=="Washington"]
```

Comment: I suggest using a dictionary, instead of defining new variables every time.

Comment: Why do you want to section the main dataframe into seperate dataframes?, i guess that 's not very manageable.

Comment: I am new to python so I may be thinking about this the wrong way. Each row contains data over time that I want to take a linear regression over. I want to be able to keep track of the metric and city that I'm regressing. I'll look into dictionaries and potentially just adding columns that save the slope and y-intercept values from the regression.